# Fastest way to search DynamoDB by calculated value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table which contains columns names A and B (both numeric). I would like to find all rows which satisfy A-B < 0. What would be the fastest way to do this assuming that we may have as many as 100000 rows that need to be scanned ?

I would be using a Lambda function so the idea is to have least possible memory and CPU cost.

Comment: Do you definitely have to use DynamoDB? If this is a common use case in your domain, maybe a different database would be better suited?

It is possible with Dynamo, but you might be better off using streams or something to maintain a running cache of such values as updates to the table happen rather than doing it on-demand.

Comment: The easiest and most efficient way is to have another attribute C = A-B. Then your query is for C < 0, which DynamoDB can easily handle.

Comment: @MatthewPope - that's way simpler, not sure why I didn't think of that!

Comment: The attributes get updated from time to time and may need to be compared (in the future) to something like current time. Precalculating would not be an option then.